# Simple delete HQL and "unexpected end of subtree"

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

When I run these two lines , I end up with "unexpected end of subtree"

```
String query = "delete from InvoiceReportStatus invoiceReportStatus";
entityManager.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

It was working fine before , may be before updating the hibernate version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DELETE` statement in SQL (as well as in HQL) doesn't accept alias.
Simply use `delete from InvoiceReportStatus`.

Comment: with alias we have to have a where clause, this one works as well   "delete from InvoiceReportStatus invoiceReportStatus where 1=1"